# find by reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so i have 2 models:

```
create_table "holders", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "faceid"
 t.integer  "badges_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
add_index "holders", ["badges_id"], :name => "index_holders_on_badges_id"

create_table "badges", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.text     "description"
 t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
end
```

i need 2 things:

1. to get all the badges of a certain faceid holder
2. to get all the holders of a certain badge.

i know its really noobs question but until now i didnt work with references so i dont really understood from the literature how to make the connection.

Comment: do you already have some relations between badges and holders in your DB populated, i.e. are there any holders for which badges_id is not NULL? Depending on that, I can propose different migrations: option 1 - preserve the existing references, option 2 - don't care about that since there are no references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need a many to many association on your holder and badge models. So you have to options either use `has many :through` or use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. The difference between the two can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many). I am taking the example for `has_many :through`.

You need to create three models.

```
 class Holder < ActiveRecord:Base
   has_many :badges_holders
   has_many :badges, :through => :badges_holders
 end

 class Badge < ActiveRecord:Base
   has_many :badges_holders
   has_many :holders, :through => :badges_holders
 end

 class BadgesHolder < ActiveRecord:Base
   belongs :badge
   belongs :holder
 end
```

And your migration files needs to be:

```
create_table "holders", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "faceid"
  t.timestamps
end
add_index "holders", ["badges_id"], :name => "index_holders_on_badges_id"

create_table "badges", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.timestamps
end

create_table "badges_holders", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "holder_id"
  t.integer  "badge_id"
  t.timestamps
end
```

Now you can easily use `Holder.find_by_faceid('xyz').badges` to find the all hedges held by the holder whose faced is xyz. And `Badge.first.holders` to get all the holders for the first bedge.

For your question HABTM will be a good option as you do not need any extra field in the join table, so you can just use `has_and_belongs_to_many` in both of your models and you don't need `BadgesHolder` model in that case. And for the migration of the join table, replace first line with `create_table "badges_holders", :id => false, :force => true do |t|` a and remove `t.timestamps` as the join table for HABTM should not have any other column than the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

If it's some Ruby on Rails, you must have 2 models :

```
class Holder < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :badges
end

class Badge < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :holder
end
```

Your entry called `badges_id` should not be in your `holders` table ; you should have a `holder_id` on your "badges" table.

Then, you can simply call

```
Holder.find_by_faceid('foobar').badges
```

and

```
Badge.find(1337).holder
```

If your `badge` can belongs to many holders, then you have to write a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation.

Comment: thank you @ForgetTheNorm. my models are already set, and have data in them. can i just add the has many and belongs_to line in the proper models file and it will be connected after restarting the server?

Comment: unfortunately, not. you need to have references in both tables. the way it is set up in the db now, it is easy to do 1-to-N between badges and holders (e.g. each badge may have multiple holders, but each holder has at most one badge), but you need N-to-N, so you need a third table for badges-holders relations to implement that. Don't panic it's still possible without erasing your data, but juts adding `has_and_belongs_to_many` won't do the trick.